# Storing Serialized Video files to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I currently am faced with a need to host 20 small video files for my website. I know I could just host them with my project in a folder but I came a crossed this article.

http://www.kindblad.com/2008/04/how-to-store-files-in-ms-sql-server.html

The thought of storing the file in the db had not occurred to me. My question is would there be a performance increase or decrease by storing the files as bit data in the db versus just streaming the data. I like the idea of having the data in the db for portability and having control and who gets access to the videos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a pressing need to store them in a database, I wouldn't, personally. You can still control who gets access to which files by using a handler to validate access to the file. One big problem that the method in that article has is that it doesn't support reading a byte range - so if someone wants to seek to the middle of a video, for example, they would have to wait for the whole thing to download. You'd want it to be able to support the range header, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429947/supporting-resumable-http-downloads-through-an-ashx-handler).

Comment: Thanks for the information Matt this was something I had not taken into consideration great comment.