# How to get IIS to serve HTTP connection from custom source with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis

Here's the scenario: I want IIS to be able to serve URLs from custom sources provided by my code. One example of this would be to serve files from an SQL database instead of the file system (this is an example however, I know about SQL server file tables and those are not the appropriate solution).

I know about HTTP handlers (*.ashx), but somehow, those never play nice with anything. I never got IE's resume download feature to work with them, not to mention streaming video files from mobile devices. There has to be a **ton** of code in IIS somewhere which decides how to handle all these cases, and I wouldn't want to rewrite it all from scratch and risk missing something critical.

What I'm looking for (and I *think* it's simple enough) is some callback which asks for some part of the data and lets IIS handle the HTTP response details. If that's not possible, is there any other solution which does not include HTTP handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You can add resumable feature to `ASHX` files, but needs your implementation as well. because for supporting resume, you need to support `accept-ranges` and implement it as well in your code. for more info you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429947/supporting-resumable-http-downloads-through-an-ashx-handler).
So, it isn't possible to assign your duties to the IIS, because IIS just can handle your requests according to the handle list that you've provided. IIS can't understand database and you must write your own code.